# Way to allow anonymous request to intermediate endpoint in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have app that work with decks (decks of one trading card game).

My security config:

```java
    @Bean //httpSecurity прототип
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/registration", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/static/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

and now I want to unsecure intermediate endpoint:

```
GET /decks <-- secured. return view with all decks of specified user
GET /decks/{id} <-- must be not secured. return single deck view by its id
GET /decks/{id}/edit <-- must be secured. return view for editing deck.
```

Is there are way to allow via Spring Security anonymous calls for `GET /decks/{id}`?

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: If you are using Spring MVC, I recommend `mvcMatchers` instead of `antMatchers` for security reasons.

`authorizeRequests` works like catch blocks, with the larger scoped expressions at the bottom. So, to "catch" `/decks/{id}`, I'd do:

```java
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
    .mvcMatchers("/", "/registration", ...).permitAll()
    .mvcMatchers("/decks/{id}").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

This will permit `/decks/{id}`, but not `decks` or `/decks/{id}/*`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `/decks/{\\d+}` in `permiteAll` statement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).